# How to fix this - "Gas estimation errored with the following message"?

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain

Hi there I'm trying to deploy this contract - https://vscode.blockscan.com/bsc/0xce9c5d8cf8673808e2b164f24d7b823d7c0004c4 
Trying just to learn solidity by copying different smart contracts that was already created and playing with the code of it. But when trying to deploy this contract I got an error:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":5352403973745893}
```

I use these constructor arguments - Name_ - USDT; Symbol_ - USDT; Decimals - 18; initialBalance_ - 1000000000; SIGNATURE_ - [];
FEERECEIVER_: - one of my wallets address.
I try to change everything, looked for a lot of tutorials, etc... But nothing helps me to fix this problem. Could anyone explain what am I doing wrong here?

P.S: I have enough bnb to cover the gas fee.

Comment: Am having this same error.
am not sure if this is a new sort of issue but hopfully someone will be able to help as to what usually cause this kind of error.

Comment: As I have noticed the problem was with payable line in my case, I just deleted it and it worked as I really had no need in these  functions in my token.

Comment: As it is the question is to generic. The problem is in the constructor, you should provide the parameters used when deploying it.